# Assertion failure ios [UICGColor encodeWithCoder:]

Tags: ios, objective-c

Assertion failure in -`[UICGColor encodeWithCoder:]`, `/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.16/UIColor.m:1455`

App is crashing when opening mail from `UIActivityViewController`

Comment: from simulator or real device???

Comment: In Both, it happen when trying to appearing Facebook sharing dialog or sending mail through UIActivityViewController.